# Sharing mp3 data from Internal Storage

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I am trying to save my sounds private in the Internal Storage and than share them but my App always crash when i press the share button

```
public void savesSound(){

    FileOutputStream fos;
    String FILENAME = "sharedsound.mp3";
    File f = new File(FILENAME);

    try {
        InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ichbin);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        fos.close();
        Log.i("Tag","Finish");
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and the Share button

```
            FileInputStream fin = null;
            try {
                fin = openFileInput("sharedsound.mp3");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(fin.toString());
            shareIntent.setType("audio/*");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey Check this out Dude");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `toString()` on an `InputStream` does not provide a path that can be used by `Uri.parse()`.

Second, you cannot share a file from internal storage with other apps via a `file://` `Uri`, as the other apps do not have access to the file.

You can [use `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to serve your files to third-party apps. This is covered in one of [the Android training modules](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html), and [here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) that shares a PDF, originally packaged as an asset, from internal storage.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help but that realy didn´t helped me ,because I have a Soundboard App and I want to share a sound when I press a button.

Comment: @Komeil: You are welcome to use `FileProvider` to share a sound when the user presses a button.

Comment: I Finaly could Set up this funktion and came to a new idea that I can change the notification Sound with a Button have you may be a ideo wehre I can get help